# how to disable the automatic y-axis range (scaling) in a VB .NET Windows app

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am showing 8 graphs of sinusoidal data.
I want the Y-axis range to be fixed  ( 2047 to -2047 ).  By "Y-axis range" I mean the column of Y-axis numbers displayed to the left of the chart.

But it automatically adjusts the Y-axis range so that the range maximum and minimum is same as maximum and minimum encountered values.

Am using: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

ChartType = FastLine

I don't see any control for Y-axis range.

Comment: Which charting library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the max & min range properties for Y-axis:
Chart props > CharAreas collection > Axis collection > Scale > Y axis > maximum & Minimum

...and change from "Auto" to the range you want.

Ha-cha!